# Ошибка при парсинге(pythone)

Tags: json

Дела вот чём я получаю историю сообщении и когда я пытаюсь парсить json мне показывает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/vk_api/venv/gg.py", line 11, in <module>
    message =  response['items'][0]['body']
KeyError: 'items'
```

Вот код:

```
import requests

from data import VkData

response = requests.get(VkData.api_url + 'messages.getHistory?access_token=' + VkData.token + '&v=5.52',
                       {'user_id': VkData.user_id, 'count': 1})

result = response.text


import json

response = json.loads(result)

message =  response['items'][0]['body']

print(message)
```

парсю из этого:

```
{"response":{"count":1201,"items":[{"id":8331,"body":"1","user_id":251343550,"from_id":409705263,"date":1534601051,"read_state":0,"out":1,"random_id":1199328298}],"in_read":8331,"out_read":8263}}
```

ПОМОГИТЕ

Comment: У `response` нет ключа `items`. Скорее всего должно быть так `response['response']['items'][0]['body']`

Comment: Да спасибо огромное помогли!